# Export to $\LaTeX$

Tags: export, latex

I have a 10 page document typed in Mathematica.  I need to have in $\LaTeX$ format.  I do not know the first thing about $\LaTeX$.  Is there a way to convert my document to $\LaTeX$?

Comment: does TeXForm[] do what you want? If so, copy and paste output into a LaTex doc.

Comment: Mathematica LaTeX export is not super reliable from my experience, and I wouldn't personally expect it to give great and professional looking results in any attempt to convert the whole 10 page document to LaTeX in one go. Your best bet is to probably take this opportunity to learn LaTeX, unfortunately.

Comment: You can use Save As... and choose LaTeX. "I do not know the first thing about LaTex."  <- LaTeX output from Mathematica often needs additional editing, which will be difficult to do if you do not know any LaTeX.  LaTeX is not a format like Word or PDF.  It is more like a programming language that you need at least a minimal familiarity with to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the docs:

> In the notebook front end, Save As exports the active notebook as a
>   TeX file.

Since you do not know LaTeX, you can try to open it in LyX.  If you succeed, you should be able to make any basic edits you need.